# Which .NET targets to use for a maximum compability of a .NET class library while maintaining a small package?

Tags: .net, .net-core, .net-standard

The .NET "system" (.NET Framework, .NET Standard, .NET Core, .NET 5) has grown over time, and now consists out of various derivatives (Framework, Standard, Core, .NET 5), API versions (CLR), and versions (.NET Framework 2.0, 3.5, 4.0, 4.5, ...).

As a class library creator for the .NET "system", I want to provide a wide compatibility: my library should be able to be consumed in various derivatives, API versions, and versions, without causing errors/warnings at compile time (e.g. "One or more packages are incompatible...").

My source code is designed to "compile" for .NET Framework 2.0, 3.5, 4.0, 4.5, 4.8, .NET Standard 2.0, .NET Core 2.1, .NET Core 3.1, .NET 5).

Now I want to provide a (NuGet) package that contains a bare minimum .NET targets, but maintains compatibility with all "major" .NET "flavors".

My plan is to provide .NET targets for the first version after a CLR change (.NET Framework 2.0, 4), for .NET Standard 2.0, .NET Core 2.1, .NET Core 3.1, and .NET 5.

My question: Is this target selection sufficient for "maximum" compatibility (starting from CLR 2.0), can some targets be removed from the list, or are there missing targets?

Comment: Do you *really* have to support the .NET 2.0 & .NET 3.5? All currently supported Windows comes with .NET 4.5 or above activated by default (and can't be disabled), so if you target .NET Standard 1.1, you're automatically compatible with all currently supported default .NET Framework installation, all .NET Core ever and will be released (including .NET 5), all currently supported Mono, Xamarin, Unity and UWP variants.

Comment: @Martheen: At first, I did not include .NET Framework 4.0 and below (was starting from .NET Framework 4.5). Then I received a number of requests for also supporting .NET Framework 2.0/3.5/4.0, since their end products have to maintain a compatibility with Windows XP, and their customers only have .NET Framework 2.0. Personally, my end products are in .NET Core 3.1 (and future are in .NET 5). However, I don't want to miss the opportunity of being a part of those end products as well. And yes, Windows XP and Windows Server 2003 in production in 2020 and ongoing :(

Comment: Well, just targeting .NET 2.0 (which is compatible with 3.5), 4.0, and .NET Standard 1.1 is enough to cover all the bases.

Comment: Thanks, could you create an answer out of your comment?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have digged through the reference @Martheen has provided within his [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65017994/1016105).

Based on the following statement from the [.NET Standard documentation about which .NET Standard version to be target](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/net-standard#which-net-standard-version-to-target), I am now using the list below the quote.

> However, targeting lower .NET Standard versions introduces a number of
> support dependencies. If your project targets .NET Standard 1.x, we
> recommend that you *also* target .NET Standard 2.0. This simplifies the
> dependency graph for users of your library that run on .NET Standard
> 2.0 compatible implementations, and it reduces the number of packages they need to download.

1. **.NET Framework 2.0** *- for .NET Framework >= 2.0 <= 3.5*
2. **.NET Framework 4.0** *- for .NET Framework >= 4.0 < 4.5*
3. **.NET Standard 1.1** *- for .NET Framework >= 4.5, .NET Core >= 1.0, .NET >= 5, Mono >= 4.6, Xamarin.IOS >= 10.0, Xamarin.Mac >= 3.0, Xamarin.Android >= 7.0, UWP >= 10.0, Unity >= 2018.1*
4. **.NET Standard 2.0** *- for .NET Framework >= 4.6.1, .NET Core >= 2.0, .NET >= 5, Mono >= 5.4, Xamarin.IOS >= 10.14, Xamarin.Mac >= 3.8, Xamarin.Android >= 8.0, UWP >= 10.0.16299, Unity >= 2018.1*
5. **.NET Standard 2.1** *- .NET Core >= 3.0, .NET >= 5, Mono >= 6.4, Xamarin.IOS >= 12.16, Xamarin.Mac >= 5.16, Xamarin.Android >= 10.0*

This provides both, compatibility for .NET Framework 2.0 and above, and fewer support dependencies for newer targets (see quote above).